# Pytorch pack/optimize many models into one GPU

Tags: pytorch

Does pytorch offer any facilities or wrappers to pack several instances of a model into a single GPU and jointly optimize them (eg each with different optimizer settings, or with different training instances)?

Comment: No! Just running another training code would solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, are you suggesting that if I launch 10 training processes targeting the same GPU I will be able to maximize utilization, or will they have to run sequentially?  My goal is to make the most efficient use of the GPU I can and currently running one model/training process per GPU only utilizes about 10%.

Comment: If you launch 10 process targetting the same gpu, they will run as separate process sharing the same gpu. In short, they will be running in parallel.

Comment: Would they consume the same amount of GPU memory as packing ten models in one process?  I imagine there might be some per-process overhead.

Comment: If you try to run all models in one process, then things will happen sequentially and thus inefficient. You can try to use python's multiprocessing library to run in parallel but figuring that out to get some small amount of memory efficiency is going to be too much effort compared to just running 10 scripts.